# rename files with multiple file extensions

Tags: bash, shell

I have hundreds of pdf files named in the following form:

```
a.php?ano=1&tp=O&np=1&lg=62&gp=TOTAL&id=1516
a.php?ano=1&tp=O&np=1&lg=62&gp=TOTAL&id=1517
a.php?ano=1&tp=O&np=1&lg=62&gp=TOTAL&id=1518
a.php?ano=1&tp=O&np=1&lg=62&gp=TOTAL&id=1519
```

and I need to rename them this way:

```
a_1516.pdf
a_1517.pdf
a_1518.pdf
a_1519.pdf
```

How can I rename them from command line?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I haven't found something similar. I just saw examples on how rename files with same extension :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `rename` from Perl (standalone command):

```
rename -n 's/\.php.*=/_/;s/$/.pdf/' a.php*
```

> `-n`: No Action: show what files would have been renamed.

If everything looks okay, remove `-n`.

Comment: or `rename -n 's/\.php.*=(\d+)$/_$1.php/' a.php*`

Answer (score 1):

A pure `bash` approach approach with its built-in `regEx` feature with the `~` operator.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in a.php*
do
    [[ $file =~ ^([[:alnum:]])(.*)=([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]
    mv -v "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"_"${BASH_REMATCH[3]}".pdf
done
```

Comment: under [tag:bash] *`regex`* are performance killer! Prefer to use: `mv $file a_${file##*=}.php`

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner would be

for f in "a.php?ano=1&tp=O&np=1&lg=62&gp=TOTAL&id="*; do mv "${f}" "${f/.php?ano=1&tp=O&np=1&lg=62&gp=TOTAL&id=/_}.pdf"; done

Comment: Also autocompletion in bash/zsh should help to compose the line,